# make asp.net formsauth cookie smaller with base64 encoding

Tags: asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication, base64

I am utilizing built in FormsAuthentication with an asp.net web app right now and I am adding a bit of additional information in the cookie and it is resulting in a "reasonably" large cookie size of ~500B.  This isn't huge but it has the potential to get bigger and I don't like this overhead on top of EVERY request.

By default, formsauth cookies are encoded in hexadecimal...

I am wondering if there is a clean way to override a method or something in ASP.NET so that I could change the cookie encoding to be base64 without incurring much overhead.

At the end of the day I could just create my own classes to do all of the authentication but I like having the built-in functionality with asp.net for role-providers and membership-providers.

Does anyone have any ideas or has anyone tried this?  Thanks.

Comment: The best solution probably is to not put a lot of data in cookies to begin with. The most using base64 is going to save you is a few dozen bytes. Alternatively, you can create your own cookie as well (separate from formsauth) and encode data in it anyway you like

Comment: certainly agree with not putting a lot of data in there to begin with... everything I am putting in there is fairly minimal and necessary.  even without the extra data, i don't like how big the formsauth cookies are!

Comment: also - a quick check indicates that for 500B i would save 164B...  almost 1/3 reduction...

Comment: that sounds about right. But you said "has the potential to get bigger". If you must store a lot of data in cookies, I'd go for the combination of compression and base64. Also, base64 isn't exactly compatible with cookies as is as well. (the padding `=` character isn't allowed in cookies, though it can easily be worked around)

Comment: yeah, I was planning on handling the == issue... the primary reason for the "extra data" is that there is a small amount of information for each user that will be needed for each page load - but i'd rather not hit the DB each time, and the app needs to be session-less

Comment: If there are a reasonable number of users you could add a Dictionary<int, UserData> to the server cache and refresh it from te DB every time a user logs in. Then you can save user info without sessions or adding data to the auth cookie.

Comment: @James This would be effectively the same as sessions - which we cannot use as we need to be able to run multiple instances.

Comment: @LelandRichardson cache != sessions. The difference is that cache can be automatically deleted at random times to save memory. So basically, when the cache isn't there, you just load it up from the database. This happens to also work across multiple servers, you just load it up the "first time" you get a request from that user on that server

Comment: it turns out in .Net there is this overload:

     internal static string Encrypt(FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket, bool hexEncodedTicket)

if hexEncodedTicket is false it will base64 it in a safe way using HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode. Of course you'd have to use reflection to do that.